# AWS CLI Query Cloudformation to populate Jenkins Extensible choice parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, jenkins-groovy

I'm new to groovy and much appreciate your help.

In my Jenkins, I'm using extensible choice parameter to populate a list using AWS CLI command.

When I execute the command in server it is providing me the expected output. But it is not generating in Jenkins.

Following is the code snippet.

```
def proc = "aws cloudformation --profile myconfig list-stacks --stack-status-filter CREATE_COMPLETE --stack-status-filter UPDATE_COMPLETE --region us-east-1".execute() | "grep "..-02-"".execute() | "grep \"StackName\"".execute() | "cut -d':' -f2".execute() | "tr ',' ' '".execute() | "tr '\"' ' '".execute() | "sed \"s/\$/,/g\"".execute() | "paste -sd ' '".execute() | "awk '{\$1=\$1;print}'".execute() | "sed -r '/^\\s*\$/d'".execute() 

def Items = []
proc.in.eachLine {line ->         
    

Items.add(line.split()[3])
}

return Items
```

Comment: Did you try to execute the command from the Jenkins master? It must work from the server (master) before it can work from Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to get the list of CloudFormation stack names.
I'm using **Active Choice Parameter** from Jenkins [Active Choice plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) with the following code:

```
def aws_cmd = "aws cloudformation list-stacks \
               --query StackSummaries[].StackName \
               --stack-status-filter CREATE_COMPLETE \
               --stack-status-filter UPDATE_COMPLETE \
               --region us-east-1 \
               --output text \
               --profile myconfig"

def aws_cmd_output = aws_cmd.execute()
//aws_cmd_output.waitFor() // usually not required
def error = aws_cmd_output.err.text
def stacks = aws_cmd_output.text.tokenize()

if (error) {
    return [error]
} else {
    return stacks
}
```

The script returns an error in case it cannot retrieve the list of stacks.
It should work with **Extensible Choice Parameter** as well.

**Note!** You should allow `cloudformation:List*` actions for IAM role that is used on Jenkins.